Include logging attributes in OpenTelemetry autoinstrumentation for ASP.NET Core
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API running in k8. The pipeline is configured to use OpenTelemetry injecting AutoInstrumentation.
I need to add extra information about the user in every log of the requests. I created a middleware that add it something similar to this:
using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "username", "some username" }
}))
{
    await _next(context);
}

The problem is that the attribute is not sent to the OT collector when running in k8.
I tested locally adding the OT nuget packages and the middleware works well, I can see the value in the console (using ConsoleExporter). The OpenTelemetry documentation explains that you need set IncludeScope logging property at registration time like this:
builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry(logging =>
{
    ...
    logging.IncludeScopes = true;
    logging.IncludeFormattedMessage = true;
}

The issue is that there is no documentation for the AutoInstrumentation. Someone can point me on how to do it?

The autoinstrumentation is meant for those without access to the code, if you have access, my advice would be to add the otel libraries then have the k8s side inject the endpoint only.

Hi @MartinDotNet. We have more than 40+ applications and I don't want (at least for the moment), adding the configuration in each application (is not easy as builder.AddApplicationInsights). I would like to have tracings for ASP.NET, Kubernetes, Redis, SQL Server, MongoDB, etc that is already configured in the AutoInstrumentation in the CICD. If there is a way to just indicate to include scopes, I'm perfectly fine with the current setup.

I don't believe we added that as an option, mainly because that's a code level thing, and the auto-instrumentation is meant for zero code change scenarios. You could add a ticket but I don't believe it's there right now.

As of today, the OpenTelemetry .NET Auto-Instrumentation does not have ability to enable ILogger scopes. Your only option today is to use manual instrumentation.
If you open a feature request in the https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-instrumentation/issues repo, the maintainers can consider adding support for it. (I believe it is a simple addition, and the ask is reasonable)
